# .html to show most recent image

Tags: javascript, php, html, image

What I have:
A .html on a computer in my local network at work, without a web server. The index.html is therefore accessed through file:// and not http://.

What I want:
A .html that shows the most recent image in a folder and automatically refreshes. I have a program taking screenshots every X seconds and saving them as "NameHHMMSS.jpg".

Is this possible without Web Server, PHP installations and so on? Thank you in advance!

Comment: if `Name` in the file name is actually fixed you might be able to use the onerror event on Image object or a a hidden image element when attempting to load an image, generate or count up a current HHMMSS, which could attempt to continuously load new images every second, if its not errored then set it into the img element which is shown

Comment: Thank you for the quick response! The name part is fixed, and your theory sounds plausible. I'm a beginner at this. Can you write me an example code?

Comment: You need a server side coding lang like php, js, asp etc.. you cant auto update images with html.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a function to dynamically generate the filename and load the image. Then you can use `setTimeout` to call the function from within itself at a desired interval.

Here is a quick test (Notice the image name changes every 5 seconds):

```js
function generateImagePath() {
  // Replace this logic with your code to generate the path for your image
  let basePath = "../images/";

  let date = new Date();

  var randomColor = Math.floor(Math.random() * 16777215).toString(16);

  let imageName = "Name" + date.getHours() + date.getMinutes() + date.getSeconds();

  // This is just to get a sample image (this will be the path of your image)
  let imageUrl = "https://via.placeholder.com/200/" + randomColor + "/fff?text=" + imageName + ".jpg";


  return imageUrl;
}

// Function that loads/changes an image every 5 seconds
function loadImage() {

  let imageUrl = generateImagePath();

  document.getElementById("imageDiv").src = imageUrl;

  setTimeout(loadImage, 5000); // Change duration here
}

// Assign the function to be called when the page has loaded
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {
  loadImage();
});
```

```html
<body>
  <img id="imageDiv" src="#" />
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

If it is just an .html file, you can put the code below inside the `<head>` tag for the page to refresh every 5 seconds.

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5; URL=http://index.html">
```

Just edit the code above based on your requirement.